# Which processor an interrupt will be generated on?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, interrupt

In Linux, multiprocessor platform, when an interrupt is generated, which processor will it interrupt?

In my case, I have a user space program to read data from spi controller. And the user space calls read(), which has a corresponding implementation like spidev_read() in kernel space. spidev_read() will handle the spi controller's interrupt to get data out of the registers.

The user space program may be running on different processor at different times. And the spi intterrupt will also be generated on different processors.

Do they always on the same processor? I mean when user space program runs on for example processor-2, then the interrupt must be generated also on processor-2? Is this right? If yes, then which one is the leading factor to select processor to run? I mean the user space program runs on processor-2 and hence interrupt is generated for processor-2, or just the reverse case?

Comment: https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/tree/master/interrupts